# How to subtract the last value from the first value for the same time

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file that looks like

| Time | OpenIA |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-07-15 10:00:23 | 1 |
| 2022-07-15 10:01:11 | 3 |
| 2022-07-15 10:01:11 | 2 |
| 2022-07-15 10:01:11 | 1 |
| 2022-07-15 10:01:11 | 3 |
| 2022-07-15 10:01:11 | 1 |
| 2022-07-15 10:01:33 | 1 |
| 2022-07-15 10:01:33 | 2 |

I'm trying to subtract the latter from the first value with the same identifier so that it would eventually turn out something like

| Time | OpenIA |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-07-15 10:00:23 | 0 |
| 2022-07-15 10:01:11 | 2 |
| 2022-07-15 10:01:33 | -1 |

To do this, I use this

```
df = pd.read_csv(DF, usecols=['Time', 'OpenIA'])
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df['Time'] = df['Time'].dt.ceil("S", 0)
b = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Time'], keep='last') - df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Time'], keep='first')
```

But instead of the expected I get

| Time | OpenIA |
| --- | --- |
| 0 days | 0.0 |
| 0 days | 0.0 |
| 0 days | 0.0 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby`.[`first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html)/[`last`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html):

```
g = df.groupby('Time', sort=False)
out = (g.first()-g.last()).reset_index()
```

output:

```
                  Time  OpenIA
0  2022-07-15 10:00:23       0
1  2022-07-15 10:01:11       2
2  2022-07-15 10:01:33      -1
```

Comment: sort=False isn't necessary. the order is preserved anyway.

Comment: @bpfrd in this case yes, but not in a generic one. Also `sort=False` is faster ;)

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved most of my problems with formulas

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
df.groupby('Time').agg(diff=('OpenIA', lambda x: x[-1]-x[0]) )
```

Comment: Unfortunately for some reason the whole csv looked like this 2022-07-15 10:01:33 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]